# Transform a column into variables in R

Tags: r, reshape

My current dataset :

```
order product
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  b
2  d
3  a
3  c
3  e
```

what I want

```
product order
a       1,3
b       1,2
c       1,3
d       2
e       3
```

I have tried cast, reshape, but they didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I recently spent way too much time trying to do something similar. What you need here, I believe, is a list-column. The code below will do that, but it turns the order number into a character value.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(order=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), product=c('a','b','c','b','d','a','c','e')) %>%
group_by(product) %>%
summarise(order=toString(.$order)) %>%
mutate(order=str_split(order, ', ')
```